# Android 4.2 Contacts ListView UI for own app?

Tags: android, listview, indexing, contacts, sections

I need to build an android app which is as similar as possible to the contacts app on my S4, but with other data in the list. Have the data as an ArrayList. I've googled a lot, but there seems to be no examples with the same looking or searchfield above. Is it possible and also legal to use the original contact list source with the sections and alphabetics index, where the letter is large displayed on scrolling? I'm using Android Studio and have used the template with tabs and swipe using fragments, which also should be supported, because of the detail view of the list items. What would be the most simple way to get what I need? Lots of thanks.